# SQL Challenge - Display N (1, X or All) rows with a certain column value

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, postgresql

Here's a morning challenge: you have a table with rows like this:

```
=> select * from candidates;
 id |   name   
----+----------
  1 | JOhn Doe
  2 | Melinda
  3 | Bill
  4 | Jane
(4 rows)

=> select * from evaluation order by id;
 id | score |                reason                
----+-------+--------------------------------------
  1 | RED   | Clueless!
  1 | AMBER | Came in dirty jeans
  2 | GREEN | Competenet and experienced
  2 | AMBER | Was chewing a gum
  3 | AMBER | No experience in the industry sector
  3 | AMBER | Has knowledge gaps
(6 rows)
```

John has a red, Melinda has a green and amber, Bill has just ambers while Jane hasn't been interviewed yet.

Your mission, should you choose to accept it is to generate a query that displays the results for Boss' approval. Boss likes to have results presented as:

- If a candidate has a GREEN, then display just  greens and ignore reds and ambers.
- If candidate has reds and ambers or just ambers then display all of them, but have red score appear first so he can skip ambers if RED is really bad.
- display GREY for all candidates that have not been yet interviewed ('Jane')

Rules of the game:

- No functions! Must be a single SQL query (however many sub-queries you want)
- Any SQL variant accepted, but ANSI SQL 92 or later gets you more points
- Try to avoid inline variables if you can (@foo in MySQL)

---

My own answer turned out to be in line with group-think:

```
SELECT *
FROM   evaluation e1
       NATURAL JOIN candidates
WHERE  score = 'GREEN'
        OR ( score IN ( 'RED', 'AMBER' )
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                             FROM   evaluation e2
                             WHERE  e1.id = e2.id
                                    AND score = 'GREEN') )
UNION
SELECT id,
       'GREY'              AS score,
       'Not yet evaluated' AS reason,
       name
FROM   candidates
WHERE  id NOT IN (SELECT id
                  FROM   evaluation)
ORDER  BY 1,
          2 DESC
```

Comment: Constraints such as `no functions` and avoiding `inline variables` will cause solutions to avoid encapsulation of code, and introduct poor practices / anti-patterns.  Also, why SQL-92?  There have been many revisions since, and no platform is fully compatible with SQL-92 or any of ther other standards any way.

Comment: No functions to make it a challenge, and SQL-92 or later to have it more or less portable - not using very platform specific stuff. Play along nonetheless!

Comment: Are you asking us to do your homework for you?

Comment: Is this a real question?  Or just a game?  I'll let others play games, and save my time and effort for something constructive.  Sorry.  (If it's real, what purpose do the constraints serve?  And what is the reality of the platforms you are/maybe using?  Some platofmrs have platform specific functionallity that would help you significantly.)

Comment: Re homework: You insult me sir :) Nope it is not, I'll be posting my solution in an hour, I wanted to see if there are neater ways. It is a game with real application.

Comment: Then may I suggest that you re-focus the question to the reality, so that we may target our efforts at something real and constructive rather than abstract?  (Portability of SQL is a massive constraint, often a fallacy, and should only be included if Required as opposed to "nice to have")

Comment: No insult intended, just an odd question 'tis all.

Comment: @Dems: I disagree with you: I start off with portable code and only go proprietary when there is a proven reason e.g. ill performing query. It's just a matter of taste, so the OP is not wrong to specify SQL-92 if they desire (and are willing to pay for it ;)

Comment: @onedaywhen - Not taking advantage of CROSS APPLY, windowing functions, and other Exceptionally powerfull and performant functionality serves to accomplish several negative aspects:  Lower performance (increased hardware cost, reduced software response), increased development time, reduced maintainability, but does serve to increase portability.  However, I have never yet encountered an enterprise need for portable code.  It is opinion though, it's just that mine has ranked cross-platform SQL as a very low priority (and poor cost/benefit) due to my industry experience :)

Comment: @Konrads - Did you forget that you were going to be "posting my solution in an hour"

Comment: @Dems: "I have never yet encountered an enterprise need for portable code" -- depending on what you mean by 'enterprise'. I worked on a product that needed to work on Access, SQL Server or Oracle depending on the enterprise we sold to i.e. hard to sell a SQL Server product to an enterprise already invested in Oracle. Writing portable SQL code was a very important requirement for us the *supplying* enterprise.

Comment: @Dems: also consider premature optimisation: you are going to have to try hard to come up with a query that runs slower than the blink of an eye using the OP's sample data ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is transitional SQL-92:

```
SELECT c.name, e.*
  FROM candidates AS c
       JOIN (
             SELECT *
               FROM evaluation
              WHERE score = 'GREEN'
             UNION
             SELECT *
               FROM evaluation AS e1
              WHERE score IN ('AMBER', 'RED')
                    AND NOT EXISTS (
                                    SELECT * 
                                      FROM evaluation AS e2
                                     WHERE e2.id = e1.id
                                           AND e2.score = 'GREEN'
                                   )                                    
            ) AS e 
          ON c.id = e.id
UNION
SELECT c.name, c.id, 'GREY', '(not interviewed)'
  FROM candidates AS c
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT *
                     FROM evaluation AS e 
                    WHERE e.id = c.id
                   )
ORDER BY id, score DESC;
```

---

Alternate (Intermediate SQL-92):

```
SELECT c.name, e.id, e.score, e.reason 
  FROM candidates AS c
       JOIN (
             SELECT *
               FROM evaluation
             EXCEPT
             SELECT *
               FROM evaluation
              WHERE score IN ('AMBER', 'RED')
                    AND id IN ( SELECT id FROM evaluation WHERE score = 'GREEN' )
            ) AS e 
          ON c.id = e.id
UNION
SELECT name, id, 'GREY' AS score, '(not interviewed)' AS reason
  FROM candidates
 WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM evaluation )
ORDER BY id, score DESC;
```

Comment: I also tried to use relational operators (avoiding `OUTER JOIN` and instead using `NOT EXISTS` for [semidifference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29), for example) to make it portable to other non-SQL relational DBMSs, noting that display order is non-relational ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
        c.id                       AS id
      , c.name                     AS name
      , COALESCE(e.score, 'GREY')  AS score
      , e.reason                   AS reason
FROM 
        candidates    c
    LEFT JOIN
        evaluation    e
            ON e.id = c.id
WHERE
        e.score = 'GREEN'
    OR
        NOT EXISTS
          ( SELECT *
            FROM evaluation    ee
            WHERE ee.id = c.id
              AND ee.score = 'GREEN'
          )
ORDER BY
        id      ASC
      , score   DESC
```

Comment: +1 The [Mimer SQL-92 Validator](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser92/index.tml) says yours is intermediate SQL-92 but I had thought table correlation names in the `ORDER BY` would violate; I had to remove them to get yours to work in SQL Server and it still validates as intermediate SQL-92 on Mimer.

Comment: Well done! on PostgreSQL the c.score in order by must be replaced with just 'score'

Comment: If it fails on SQL Server and PostgreSQL I'm suspecting the Mimer validator is wrong and that for SQL-92 compliance you should change `ORDER BY c.id ASC, c.score DESC` to `ORDER BY id ASC, score DESC;` i.e. lose the table correlation name `c` in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Yes, corrected. That's why it's not good to have aliases same as column names.

Answer (score 0):

```
           SELECT c.id,
               c.name,
               nvl(e.score, 'GREY'),
               nvl(e.reason, 'Not yet interviewed')
          FROM candidates c, evaluation e
         where c.id = e.id(+)
           and ((e.score = 'GREEN') or
               (e.score in ('RED', 'AMBER') and not exists
                (select null
                    from evaluation e2
                   where e2.id = e.id
                     and e2.score = 'GREEN')) or e.score is null)
         order by c.id, e.score desc;
```

Comment: Welcome on SO, here, it is a good practice to explain why to use your solution and not just how. That will make your answer more valuable and help further reader to have a better understanding of how you do it. I also suggest that you have a look on our FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.ID
    , A.NAME
    , B.SCORE
    , B.REASON
FROM CANDIDATES A
LEFT JOIN EVALUATION B
    ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE B.SCORE = 'GREEN'
UNION
SELECT A.ID
    , A.NAME
    , COALESCE(B.SCORE,'GREY')
    , B.REASON
FROM CANDIDATES A
LEFT JOIN EVALUATION B
    ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM EVALUATION WHERE SCORE = 'GREEN')
ORDER BY ID, SCORE DESC;
```

Comment: First select all the ID having score = green and then select the rest of the ids excluding the id's having score = green.

Comment: Don't use comments to explain your own answers. If you need to describe it, use post editing.